# How do you rephrase this sentence as concisely as possible?

Tags: grammar

> Go there and get top marks on your exam to make us proud and beat
>   your bullies to a pulp to make us proud.

Is often rephrased as:

> Go there and get top marks on your exam and beat
>   your bullies to a pulp to make us proud.

However, both of them are not really synonymous, because it can be interpreted that "to make us proud" is only attached to the sentence "beat your bullies to a pulp". So is there a way to reformulate this without repeating "to make us proud" twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the repetition of *to make us proud*, you can use this construction:

> To make us proud, go there to both get top marks on your exam and beat your bullies to a pulp.

Note that this assumes you are beating your bullies to a pulp when going there.

---

If the sentence means that you can beat your bullies to a pulp *anywhere* (and *go there* only applies to getting top marks on your exam), then things have to get a bit more creative in order to avoid the following ambiguity with the three uses of *and*:

> 1. (go there and get top marks on your exam) **and** beat your bullies to a pulp

This is the interpretation we want.

> 2. go there **and** (get top marks on your exam and beat your bullies to a pulp)

This is the original interpretation, which has already been rephrased.

> 3. go there **and** get top marks on your exam **and** beat your bullies to a pulp

This is something different yet again. But since the original sentence doesn't use *to make us proud* three times, it's not accurate.

---

To achieve the first interpretation, one of the following would work:

> To make us proud, both (1) go there and get top marks on your exam and (2) beat your bullies to a pulp.
>
> To make us proud, both go there **to get** top marks on your exam and beat your bullies to a pulp.

Note that the meaning of the sentence is altered very subtly in the final sentence, which says that your purpose for going there is to get top marks, not simply that you go there and happen to get top marks (which makes us proud).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Go there" is being applied to both getting top marks and beating the bullies to a pulp,

> Go there and both get top marks on your exam and beat your bullies to a pulp to make us proud

should accomplish what you are setting out to say.
However, if "Go there" is only describing the top marks, then this should work:

> To make us proud, go there and get top marks on your exam and beat your bullies to a pulp

This is not a particularly good example though since the two uses of "and" are so close together. Consider another way to structure the sentence, such as

> Go there and get top marks on your exam. If you also beat your bullies to a pulp, you will make us proud

if you require "go there" to only be describing the "top marks". That may be too much of a digression from the original structure so it may not be a great choice. Either way, one of these options should solve your problem.